# Remove objects from an array where their properties are not found in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of Special objects as follows:

```
var allSpecials = []; //Yet to be populated
```

When populated, each special object in the array looks like this,

e.g.

```
{address: "250 Manukau Road", category: "Breakfast Special", coords: so, cusine_type: "Japanese", establishment_type: "Restaurant", …}
{address: "557 Manukau Rd", category: "Dinner Special", coords: so, cusine_type: "Italian", establishment_type: "Bar", …}
```

I want to remove for example, element 0 in the allSpecials array as it's category, "Breakfast Special", is not found in the following array

```
specialCategories = ["Happy Hour", "Dinner Special", "Lunch Special"];
```

How can I go about this?

Many thanks

Comment: This is not how SO works, you have to post some of your code/efforts first then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash [keyby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keyBy), [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) and [values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) functions.

```
const categorySpecialMap = keyBy(allSpecials, 'category');
const targetSpecials = values(pick(categorySpecialMap, specialCategories));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is to remove elements whose categories are not found in the `specialCategories` array?

Given an array:

```js
const allSpecial = [{address: "250 Manukau Road", category: "Breakfast Special", coords: "so", cusine_type: "Japanese", establishment_type: "Restaurant"}, {address: "557 Manukau Rd", category: "Dinner Special", coords: "so", cusine_type: "Italian", establishment_type: "Bar"}, {address: "333", category: "x"}]
```

and another array:

```js
const specialCategories = ["Breakfast Special", "Happy Hour", "Dinner Special", "Lunch Special"];
```

You can filter the `allSpecials` array where the category isn't included in the specialCategories array like so:

```js
allSpecials.filter(x => specialCategories.includes(x.category))
```

OR

If you want to dynamically populate `specialCategories` with only objects that match, you can do:

```js
myArrayOfObjects.forEach(e => {
  if (specialCategories.includes(e.category)) {
     allSpecials.push(e)
  }
})
```